# Typescript + Webpack + Heroku = Bundle.js not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, webpack

I've been banging my head on this issue all day and SO has a lot of clues, but I can't seem to piece them together correctly with the current set of behaviors.

- App works fine locally
- Heroku local works fine
- Heroku log has no errors
- Build log has no errors

Piecing them together, what results is an empty page with just the HTML file. Upon inspection, we get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) bundle.js:1

```js
//package.json

"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
  "build-dev": "webpack -d --mode development",
  "build-prod": "webpack -p --mode production",
  "server-dev": "nodemon server/index.ts",
  "react-dev": "webpack -d --watch",
  "start": "node server/index.ts",
  "build": "tsc",
  "postinstall": "npm run build"
},
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "react": "^16.12.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-particles-js": "^2.7.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
  "typescript": "^3.8.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
  "@types/node": "^12.7.4",
  "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
  "@types/react-css-transition-replace": "^2.1.3",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
  "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.3",
  "@types/react-vertical-timeline-component": "^2.5.0",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
  "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "html-webpack-template": "^6.2.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
  "react-css-transition-replace": "^4.0.2",
  "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
  "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^2.5.0",
  "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
  "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
  "three": "^0.113.2",
  "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
  "vanta": "^0.5.10",
  "webpack": "^4.41.6",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
}
```

```js
// Webpack Config

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: require('html-webpack-template'),
        inject: false,
        appMountId: 'app',
        filename: 'index.html',
        title: 'My Web App'
      })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
        use: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.tsx',
      '.ts',
      '.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

```html
// index.ts

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on Port: ${port}`);
});
```

```js
// Heroku Logs 

2020-03-05T05:58:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user me@gmail.com
2020-03-05T05:59:38.707979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-03-05T05:59:38.458691+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user me@gmail.com
2020-03-05T05:59:38.458691+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 349a20a1 by user me@gmail.com
2020-03-05T05:59:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-05T05:59:46.847659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-03-05T05:59:49.706350+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-05T05:59:49.706370+00:00 app[web.1]: > empty-project@1.0.0 start /app
2020-03-05T05:59:49.706370+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/index.ts
2020-03-05T05:59:49.706371+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-05T05:59:50.255593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-05T05:59:50.020428+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on Port: 58121
2020-03-05T05:59:51.511884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-beyond-73580.herokuapp.com request_id=aed81b4e-61ee-4e4f-8b10-726d10ddfae6 fwd="107.3.131.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=571 protocol=https
2020-03-05T05:59:51.780460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bundle.js" host=warm-beyond-73580.herokuapp.com request_id=834ec783-9810-4ae7-bbfe-47f32401deca fwd="107.3.131.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=392 protocol=https
```

```js
// Heroku Build Log 

-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.11.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 8.11.3...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.3...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > empty-project@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_2111397be8b13d0f0590307d71ce21bf
       > npm run tsc
       
       
       > empty-project@1.0.0 tsc /tmp/build_2111397be8b13d0f0590307d71ce21bf
       > tsc
       
       up to date in 25.017s
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       Skipping because npm 5.6.0 sometimes fails when running 'npm prune' due to a known issue
       https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19356
       
       You can silence this warning by updating to at least npm 5.7.1 in your package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 59.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v23
       https://portfolio.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: In your `scripts` I'm not sure what `tsc` does. When you are building locally do you also run `npm build` or do you do `npm build-dev`? Try this: `"postinstall": "npm run build-prod"`

Comment: `tsc` transpiles typescript. I've tried `"postinstall": npm run build-prod` when I was debugging yesterday, but it causes errors in the heroku log and is unable to transpile typescript.

Comment: devDependencies aren't installed in production but your production apparently requires some of the devDependencies. That's probably why it is unable to transpile typescript. Does `"postinstall": npm run build-dev` work?